# Making a fixed/sticky header with 100% width in a div

Tags: html, css

I have a div with a fixed/sticky header and content. It works in that when I scroll the content the header doesn't move.

But I can't get the header width to be 100% of the parent div.

```css
#main {
  background-color: lightcoral;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}

.menu {
  background-color: lightyellow;
  position: relative;
}

.header-wrapper {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  position: absolute;
}

.header {
  background-color: lightskyblue;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.content {
  padding-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  other content<br />other content<br />other content<br />
</div>
<div id="main">
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="header-wrapper">
      <div class="header">
        header
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Here is your answer:

```css
#main {
    background-color: lightcoral;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    resize: both;
    overflow: auto;
}

.menu {
    background-color: lightyellow;
    position: relative;
}

.header-wrapper {
    background-color: lightgrey;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0vh;
}

.header {
    background-color: lightskyblue;
}

.content {
    padding-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    other content<br />other content<br />other content<br />
</div>
<div id="main">
    <div class="menu">
        <div class="header-wrapper">
            <div class="header">
                header
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />content<br />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works great. Thank you. I did not know why I did not think of/try sticky. I need to read up on what `1vh` means....